# Timestamps across the network are appearing in the future!

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps

I [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496878/reduce-integers-if-covering-0-9#comment18471014_13496878), I replied to a comment. The comment I replied to then appeared *below* my comment with a timestamp in the *future*:

[image]

The comments will now just appear out of sequence, but at the time the timestamp was in the future.

This has been posted a couple of times in the past, but it appears to be happening again.

---

**Update:** There have been reported incidents of this also occurring in other areas where timestamps are generated, such as the closed question notices and in chat.

Comment: Really, 'in 31 seconds'? Oi, someone nicked my timemachine!

Comment: Time is ‮ !gnilevarnu

Comment: Now my head hurts, thanks >.>

Comment: Who knew they even had code that compensated for times past the current time... Planning for something are we Stack Exchange? Spill the beans!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Hilariously, in IE8 `View Source`, your comment causes a `<naps/>` tag to appear instead of a `</span>`.

Comment: @Rawling hehe it used to do that in the Chrome Inspector too, but it seems like they fixed that lol

Comment: There's definitely something wonky going on. The transcript of a chat I just had has the message order flipped. And another room's info says the last message was posted [-35 seconds ago](http://i.imgur.com/9mV7Q.png). That's at least the weird stuff I see. Not sure if that's just a local thing though.

Comment: By the way, these comments' ids ordering is right. Weird.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the *cock blender*

Comment: @Bart seems likely.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Using the `<naps/>` html there are you?

Comment: They've build timemachines and precognitive robots, and they still haven't fixed the damn review???

Comment: @Yannis: And it seems they don't plan to, otherwise they would've sent the fix back in time.

Comment: it's the end of the world coming, 2012 is almost over

Comment: I'm seeing this in chat, replies that appear before the initial comment.

Comment: @animuson Probably it has something to do with events that are scheduled to happen in the future, like bounty expiration.

Comment: Very possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156383/eeek-chat-made-the-robot-precognitive

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was actually caused by the hurricane failover and our silly decision to seize FSMO roles.  When you do this to an AD environment, you have to setup the new PDC Emulator master as the authoritative time source on the network.

We, uh, didn't do that, so as a result all manner of time desynchronization has occured.  I get to take the blame for it, but I also just fixed it so I guess it's a wash.

The problem should not recur!

**Edit**

Translation: When we failed over to our secondary datacenter because of <s>Hurricane</s> SUPERSTORM Sandy, we didn't set up time synchronization correctly so our servers got out of sync.  Two submissions to different servers could thus get timestamps off by up to a minute or two.

Comment: In english for the layperson?  :-)

Comment: seize FSMO roles, AD environment, PDC Emulator. What?

Comment: @Chimera [Flexible single master operation (FSMO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_single_master_operation), [Active Directory (AD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory), [Primary Domain Controller (PDC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_Domain_Controller)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ thanks!

Comment: We can't all just blindly upvote this and pretend we know what it says! This isn't /review!

Comment: Oh, I thought this was the place to pretend to know what he's talking about and make disparaging comments toward everyone who doesn't.  *What sort of self-respecting person doesn't know what FSMO is LOL.*

Comment: But what about the flux capacitor?

Comment: Haha, sorry guys.  @DavidFullerton broke it down wonderfully.

Comment: I don't believe you. It was this and you know it: http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101214205521/bttf/images/b/b6/BTTF-game-SS-09.jpg

Answer (score 8):

This was caused by the same time sync issues as [Eeek! Chat made the robot precognitive!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156383/eeek-chat-made-the-robot-precognitive), which also has an answer by Pete with an acronym-laden explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Something bad happened to the NTP sources in the US over the weekend. You can see reports across the net, eg [here](http://puck.nether.net/pipermail/outages/2012-November/004844.html). I'd wager this is something to do with it.

Comment: "The clocks should have been marked as insane" - nice