# Eeek! Chat made the robot precognitive!

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, robots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timestamps across the network are appearing in the future!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156375/timestamps-across-the-network-are-appearing-in-the-future)

So, this is what actually happened (replies marked in freehand arrows):

[image]

And this is what SO chat claims to have happened (replies marked in freehand arrows):

[image]

We all know how incredibly awesome the robot is, but is it really precognitive? Isn't that too much awesomeness? Is there any risk of an explosion from awesomeness overload?

Comment: An issue related to this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156375/comment-appearing-after-reply-timestamp-in-future